# C# Selenium & Extent Reports: The wrong result appears on the report after a test

Tags: c#, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

First off, here is the Test Cleanup method I have that runs at the end of each test to determine and add its outcome to the Extent Report:

```
[TestCleanup]
public void AfterTest()
{
    var status = TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome;
    Status logstatus;

    switch (status)
    {
        case UnitTestOutcome.Failed:
            logstatus = Status.Fail;
            break;
        case UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive:
            logstatus = Status.Warning;
            break;
        case UnitTestOutcome.Passed:
            logstatus = Status.Pass;
            break;
        default:
            logstatus = Status.Error;
            break;

    }

    if (test != null)
    {
        test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus);
    }
}
```

What keeps happening is that if I run a test on its own and it fails, the Extent Report will display it as a fail, as it should.

[image: Here is an example.]

However, if I run this test with another, and the test that comes before it passes, then it will show the wrong result at the end of the test that fails.

[image: And here is an example of that.]

From debugging, I have found that the value of `var status = TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome` starts off as Failed then changes to Passed when it gets to the end of that second test, but I can't figure out what causes it because the second test is definitely failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am quite stuck. And I am happy to provide any more information if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add information about how you are running these tests? Is this part of a continuous integration build? Which CI vendor are you using (e.g. Azure DevOps, Jenkins, etc).

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am running these tests through Microsoft Visual Studio, using the MSTest framework. They don't run parallel to each other. It's to run automated tests on a web app my company develop. Each test is a test method within a test class. Different test classes have test methods for the area of the web app it is testing. Does this help?